# Disable drag and drop when filter criteria is present in JQGRID

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a jqgrid with sortable property where I can Drag and Drop the records to change the sequence.If filter search is performed ,then I have to prevent the Drag Drop or Reorder operation

One thought I got was to disable the drag /drop by setting sortable:false inside the after search.

```
$grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    searchOperators: true,
    afterSearch: function(){alert("hi");
        $grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{sortable :false});
    }
});
```

But this is not working? Also I want to enable the reorder when no filter search is present.

**UPDATE**: I have find a work around for this problem.

```
 afterSearch: function(){
        var filters = JSON.parse($grid.getGridParam("postData").filters);
        if(filters.rules.length)
        {               
            $grid.jqGrid('sortableRows',{disabled: true});
        }
        else
        {                           
            $grid.jqGrid('sortableRows',{disabled: false});
        }

    }.
```

But not sure is it right. How to enable the sortableRows when no filter inputs are there.

Comment: Do you use [sortableRows](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#sortable_rows) method to sort **rows** or you just use [sortable: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) option (with calls `sortableColumns` method internally) to reordering **columns**?

Comment: I use sortableRows . I am not sure how to reset it back once I clear the filter inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `sortableRows` just uses [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) on `<tbody>` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.jqueryui.js#L324)). So one can use

```js
$grid.find(">tbody").sortable("disable");
```

to disable and

```js
$grid.find(">tbody").sortable("enable");
```

to re-enable `sortableRows`. To destroy sortable one can use

```js
$grid.find(">tbody").sortable("destroy");
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/sortableRowsEnableDisable.htm) can be used to see the results. The snippet below do the same

```js
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var mydata = [
            { id: "1",  invdate: "2007-10-21", name: "test",   note: "3note",   amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
            { id: "2",  invdate: "2007-10-22", name: "test2",  note: "3note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "3",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "3note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
            { id: "4",  invdate: "2007-10-14", name: "test4",  note: "3note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
            { id: "5",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "3note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "6",  invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "3note6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
            { id: "7",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7",  note: "3note7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
            { id: "8",  invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8",  note: "3note8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "9",  invdate: "2007-09-22", name: "test9",  note: "3note9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
            { id: "10", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "3note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
            { id: "11", invdate: "2007-09-28", name: "test11", note: "3note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
            { id: "12", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "3note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }
        ],
        initDatepicker = function (elem) {
            $(elem).datepicker({
                autoSize: true,
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                showWeek: true
            });
        },
        numberTemplate = {formatter: "number", align: "right", sorttype: "number",
            editrules: {number: true, required: true},
            searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge", "nu", "nn", "in", "ni"] }},
        $grid = $("#list");

    $grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: mydata,
        colNames: ["Client", "Date", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Closed", "Shipped via", "Notes"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "name", editrules: {required: true}, width: 65 },
            { name: "invdate", align: "center", sorttype: "date", width: 80,
                formatter: "date",
                searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDatepicker } },
            { name: "amount", template: numberTemplate, width: 75 },
            { name: "tax", template: numberTemplate, width: 52 },
            { name: "total", template: numberTemplate, width: 60 },
            {name: "closed", align: "center", formatter: "checkbox", width: 70,
                edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: {value: "Yes:No", defaultValue: "Yes"},
                stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" } },
            {name: "ship_via", align: "center", formatter: "select", width: 105,
                edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "FE" },
                stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim" } },
            { name: "note", sortable: false, search: false, edittype: "textarea", width: 60 }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20],
        pager: "#pager",
        gridview: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        autoencode: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        sortname: "invdate",
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        shrinkToFit: false,
        height: "auto"
    });
    $grid.jqGrid("sortableRows");
    $("#enableSortableRows").button().click(function () {
        $grid.find(">tbody").sortable("enable");
    });
    $("#disableSortableRows").button().click(function () {
        $grid.find(">tbody").sortable("disable");
    });
    $("#destroySortableRows").button().click(function () {
        $grid.find(">tbody").sortable("destroy");
    });
});
```

```css
.ui-jqgrid-hdiv { overflow-y: hidden; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>

<div style="float:left;font-size:11px" class="ui-widget">
    <fieldset class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-jqgrid" style="float:left;margin:5px">
        <legend class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top">Enable/Disable/Destroy of sortableRows</legend>
        <button type="button" id="enableSortableRows">Enable sortableRows</button>
        <button type="button" id="disableSortableRows">Disable sortableRows</button>
        <button type="button" id="destroySortableRows">Destroy sortableRows</button>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div style="clear:left">
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I will definitely try and let you know the result

Comment: My another doubt is I want to re-enable on clearing the search filter data. But the event after Clear in the filter tool bar never gets triggered. Or I am expecting a wrong behaviour of the function I guess

Comment: @user2375298: By the way, you can click on "Show code snippet" and then on "Run code shippet" to run the code. The same code is on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/sortableRowsEnableDisable.htm) too.

Comment: @user2375298: What you mean under "Clear" the toolbar. Do you call `clearToolbar` for example inside of you custom code? In the case `afterClear` callback fired. It can be that you mean `clearSearch: true` option and small `x` button (`a.clearsearchclass`)? It follows calling of `triggerToolbar` only in case of `autosearch: true`, but you can bind `click` event to `tr.ui-search-toolbar a.clearsearchclass` to make your custom actions.